# @Font-face not working no matter what I try

Tags: fonts

Yes... this has been asked a lot on here, and I am a rookie web developer doing little experiments in my own time.

I am trying to use the CSS @font-face property, but CLUELESS as to why it won't work. I simply can't do anything to get it to work. And I've been all over Stack Overflow, W3Schools, MDN, and more - no matter how much I alter and change things thinking "it might work now" it's impossible.

My code:
[image: My code]

My result:
[image: My result]

Does anyone have an idea on what I am doing wrong? I've tried WOFF and WOFF2, altering the syntax of the directory in the CSS, and I have used Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. All of which I updated to their latest version.

Comment: Odd that you're using backslashes in CSS. Not sure if that works.

Comment: I have tried forward slashes, to no avail - sadly. :(
I will keep it as forward slashes now. That is the right way, woops!

Comment: If you check the console logs in your browser for some more information and include any error messages you see in the question (plus paste your actual css and html code into the question as well if you can) you will likely get a more accurate answer to the question a lot quicker. Good luck finding a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't confirm for sure, but some things to try:

1. Remove the comment from inside the `<style>` tag. That is an HTML comment inside a CSS file, which might confuse the browser. If you really need that comment, place it before the `<style>` tage.
2. In the `@font-face` `url`, use forward slashes `/`, not backward slashes `\`. Forward slashes are the standard for paths and URLs and only Windows uses backward slashes.
3. Also in the `url`, the leading slash (the one before `fonts`) will only work if your website is in the root of a server, e.g. if your website was at `http://example.com/index.html` and your fonts were at `http://example.com/fonts`. It might not work well in your case, since I suspect you are serving from a filesystem. So if your `index.html` is next to your `fonts` directory, use `url("fonts/gotham_bold.ttf"`).
4. If you are indeed serving your webpage filesystem, consider having a virtual server. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is very simple to install and is good to learn about Apache, still a popular server software.

Comment: Thanks for the help, all sorted. Must've missed something somehere because I swear I already tried removing the forward slash that!
Ahhh, I had back slashes when I tried removing the forward slash. That was my error.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @JackWright No problem! Please accept the answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: It's asking me to wait. Will do when it lets me! ^^